# ckEditor Image does not get saved after upload when image selected

Tags: javascript, image, upload, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to solve a riddle here. Imagine the following. The user uploads one image, which a minute later he wants to replace. Thus he clicks on the image and selects the upload button again, chooses another image and uploads it. In the editor this image is shown, but when he saves the change, the old image is shown again.

My guess is, that this is due to the fact that only the src-attribute gets updated, but not the data-cke-saved-src-attribute. The question now is: How do I change that?

I should also mention, that since I have a blur-handler, that is asking the user if he wants to discard the change. This fires whenever an dialog opens, which is why I am "refocusing" the editor using the following snippet:

```
        CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (e) {
            var dialog = e.data.definition.dialog;
            dialog.on('hide', function () {
                dis.ckEditor.focusManager.hasFocus = true;
                $('.cke').show();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Since CKEditor have nothing like "upload button" in the core you need to tell more what plugins and what CKEditor version are you using.